# Determining if a linear transformation across abstract vector spaces is surjective given a non-square coefficient matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have been having a bit of trouble with this problem. It can be viewed [here](http://linear.ups.edu/fcla/section-SLT.html), at the very bottom, question C23, the answer is provided but obviously not in enough detail. Here is the definition of the linear transformation. I understand that I must get $\vec{v}$ in terms of $\vec{u}$ but I am unsure of how to do that.
$$
T:\mathbb{C}^5 \longrightarrow P_3 \qquad
T\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e
\end{bmatrix}
\right) =
a + (b+c)x + (c+d)x^2 + (d+e)x^3
$$

All of the other examples, namely "Example SAV" (see link), have just involved taking the inverse of a coefficient matrix when the equation is of the form $A\vec{u}=\vec{v}$. However, the coefficient matrix in this example is not square, it is rectangular provided below. How do I prove that this transformation is surjective?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Surjective means that the image of the transformation (also called the *range*) is all of the target vector space. In coordinates (meaning that you have explicitly chosen a basis for the domain $\mathbb{C}^5$ and the codomain $P_3$), you want the column space (span of columns of the matrix) to be all of $\mathbb{C}^4$.

Comment: @Sammy Black is that all I need? A "proper" answer would be greatly, greatly appreciated. This has stumped me for some time.

Comment: Sure, I will copy and expound upon the hint.

Comment: @Sammy Black thank you, if you could a worked solution would be greatly appreciated so I can really piece it together, but of course it's your time. Your comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can get a basis out of this, you're done. A basis for $P_3$ is $1, x, x^2 + x^3, x^3$ and generating those suffices -- so for example, pick $a = 1$ and all the others to be 0 to get 1. Similarly pick $b=1$ and all the others to be 0 to get $x$. Picking $d = 1$ and all others 0 gets you $x^2 + x^3$ and picking $e = 1$ and all others 0 gets you $x^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surjective means that the image of the transformation $T$ (also called the range) is all of the target vector space. In coordinates (meaning that you have explicitly chosen a basis for the domain $\mathbb{C}^5$ and the codomain $P_3$), you want the column space (span of columns of the matrix) to be all of $\mathbb{C}^4$.

In order to verify the latter, we apply the Gaussian elimination algorithm, which converts
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to the reduced row-echelon form
$$
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $B$ has a pivot in each row, the transformation is onto. In fact, we can say more: the columns with pivots, namely $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, are the same columns in the original matrix who span the image of the transformation. In other words, with the notation $\mathbf{e}_j \in \mathbb{C}^5$ for the standard basis vector with $1$ in coordinate $j$ and $0$ elsewhere,
$$
\bigl\{ T(\mathbf{e}_1), T(\mathbf{e}_2), T(\mathbf{e}_3), T(\mathbf{e}_4) \bigr\} 
= \bigl\{ 1, x, x + x^2, x^2 + x^3 \bigr\}
$$
spans $P_3$.

---

**Edited to respond to comments.**

Working directly from the definition of *surjective,* given the transformation $T: \mathbb{C}^5 \to P_3$ and arbitrary $p \in P_3$, we must find $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{C}^5$ such that $T(\mathbf{v}) = p$. Start by naming coefficients for $p$:
$$
p = q + rx + sx^2 + tx^3.
$$
Since
$$
T \left( \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d\\e \end{bmatrix} \right) 
= a + (b+c)\, x + (c+d)\, x^2 + (d+e)\, x^3,
$$
by equating coefficients, we have the system of linear equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcr}
a &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &= &q \\
  &  &b &+ &c &  &  &  &  &= &r \\
  &  &  &  &c &+ &d &  &  &= &s \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &d &+ &e &= &t
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which can be represented as the augmented linear system
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1
\end{matrix}
\;\middle|\;
\begin{matrix}
q\\r\\s\\t
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$
Row reduction yields
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&0&1&1
\end{matrix}
\;\middle|\;
\begin{matrix}
q\\r-s+t\\s-t\\t
\end{matrix}
\right]. 
$$
Since the $5$th column has no pivot, the variable $e$ is free. Thus, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c\\d\\e \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} q\\r-s+t-e\\s-t+e\\t-e\\e \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} q\\r-s+t\\s-t\\t\\0 \end{bmatrix} 
+ e \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-1\\1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix},
$$
for any $e \in \mathbb{C}$. All we need to establish surjectivity is at least one solution. Here we’ve parametrized an (infinite) $1$-dimensional family of solutions to the equation $T(\mathbf{v}) = p$.

You should plug this $\mathbf{v}$ into $T$ and check that it always produces $p$.

Comment: Is there anyway to find out how they generated their particular example solution provided in the link I originally posted? In the other example, "Example SAV" (see link) they gave a way to determine the original $\vec{u}$. Is it as simple as just solving $A\vec{u}=\vec{v}$?

Comment: Yes. In your example, because the transformation maps from a $5$-dimensional space onto a $4$-dimensional space, there’s $1$ degree of freedom in the choice of a preimage of any vector in the image of $T$. In other words, for an arbitrary polynomial $p \in P_3$, you can’t find *the* vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $T(\mathbf{v}) = p$, but you can find *a* vector, and its span (i.e. all of its scalar multiples) will work as well.